# how to use public method via reflection method from another dll?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

i want to use run execute method in dll. i have 2 dll i can access my startup dll'RUN method:

This below codes can not run  Execute method another DLL(NetworkProcessor) . i want to ınvoke NetworkProcessor.IpPing class'execute method. but i can not.
how to to it using reflection?

```
public void RUN(string uri, string serverGuid)
{
    //something...
    //something...
    //something...
```

Comment: Interfaces are made for this sort of work.

Comment: i added error. you can see :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify `BindingFlags.Public` you also need to specify either `BindingFlags.Instance` or `BindingFlags.Static`, or both:

```
MethodInfo minfo = instance.GetType().GetMethod("Execute", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Currently neither is specified, causing `GetMethod` to return null.

Comment: You can also omit the BindingFlags, that should return the method too.